# PHP $_SESSION Simple securization issue

Tags: php

I am building a session array with 3 information: `mail`, `password` and `id`. mail and password i use from the POST. Note that before using the data i use `mysql_real_escape_string` for the mail and sha1 for the password. But for id I get the value from the database. The question is: Should I do  `'id'=>htmlentities($data['ENS_ID'])` instead of just `'id'=>$data['ENS_ID']` for security purpose? Sorry if my question makes no sense to you but I am a bit lost with securization. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ENS_MEMBRES WHERE ENS_MAIL = '$mail' AND ENS_PASS = '$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){

    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);   
    $_SESSION['Auth']=array(
        'mail'=>$mail,
        'password'=>$password,
        'id'=>$data['ENS_ID'],
    );
```

Comment: Why do you store the password in the session? What do you need the password during the session for?

Comment: Because I check at several occasions that the user is logged. I have a isLogged() function checking first that the sessions informations are set and also that the information are correct (check with db)

Comment: To handle the case that the information stored in the database has been altered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the ID in your session as as, but whenever you use it in another context, you have to escape it appropriately. That means:

- when using in a database query, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared)
- when outputting in an HTML page, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)
- when using as part of an url, use ([`raw`](http://php.net/rawurlencode))[`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)
- when executing external commands, use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg), or [`escapeshellcmd`](http://escapeshellcmd) respectively.
- …

Comment: Hello knittl, thanks for the reply. Are there many other when...with different ...use?

Comment: @user1162116: yes, the function you have to use depends on the context, I've only written the most common pitfalls. Other contexts might include: CSV data, JSON, XML, shell functions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not be necessary. `id` should be of numeric type. Even if it was of another type, I personally would consider it better not to escape the value that you're storing in the `$_SESSION`, but rather escape it when you're doing something with it. Do you insert the value in HTML code -> use `htmlspecialchars`. Do you plan on using it in subsequent queries? Use `mysql_real_escape_string` and so on. In any case, the `$_SESSION` should really store the original value IMHO (i.e. not escaped). After all, you need different kinds of escaping depending on what you're doing with the value.

Just consider what would happen if you required the original (unescaped) `id` at some point, or have it escaped in a different way. It would be cumbersome to unescape the value that you have put in your `$_SESSION`.

--

Note that it is better to use PDO or similar for interacting with the database in any case, at least in the long run. With prepared statements and bounded parameters, you do not even have to escape the parameters yourself.

Comment: Is there no need to securize the data coming from the database in that case? If the value I retrieve for session purpose from my database was  another type than int, should I use in that case htmlentities() ?

Comment: I have updated my answer in this respect. The answer is: I think it is preferrable to save the original value in $_SESSION and escape it whenever you're using it for doing some possibly dangerous operation, like inserting the value in HTML code or using it in queries. Depending on the type of that operation you will need different kinds of escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong! mysql_real_escape_string should be used before putting the mail string into the SQL query, but you probably want to save it in its original form, without escaping, into the session array.

The same goes for the id (or anything you fetch from the database). Only escape data when it's time to use it. Escaping differs between different context, so escaping for HTMl (with htmlentities) may not be secure in SQL context and vice versa.

Comment: I use mysql_real_escape_string before putting it in the query.. And sha1 for password also before..

Comment: Yes, but it's almost always wrong to store the escaped mail string in the session array. You want to store the string as it looked before escaping.